# Python: unorderable types: int() < range() or 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get a python script to print '@' symbols, in relation the the value held in a list. For example, if the list as [1,2,3] - the script would print:

```
1 @
2 @@
3 @@@
```

With the following code:

```
myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

x = 1

While x < range(len(myList)):
    print (x, end ='')

for frequency in myList[x]:
    print ('@')

print ('\n')
x = x + 1
```

So far I get this error "TypeError: unorderable types: int() < range()". I think I'm getting this because it can't compare a single number to a range of numbers.

But when I try to just use:

```
len(myList)
```

I get: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

Not sure what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, this is comparing the value in `x` to the value `range(...)`:

```
while x < range(len(myList)):
    print (x, end ='')
```

That's not what you want. Instead, you want to loop across those values:

```
for x in range(len(myList)):
    ...
```

Similarly, your second loop isn't going to work:

```
for frequency in myList[x]:
    print ('@')
```

Since `myList[x]` is an int, that translates as "for every value `frequency` in the the number `myList[x]`..." which doesn't really make sense. You really mean:

```
for frequency in range(myList[x]):
    print ('@')
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Please throw your code in the dustbin and look for a better approach</strike>

You'd better do this:

```
for number in yourList:
    if number <= 0:
        print("Cannot use negative numbers or zero here!")
    else:
        print ("{} {}".format(number, "@" * number))
```

Don't forget that you can get `N` copies of a string by simply multiplying this string by `N`, where `N` is a positive non-zero number.

Comment: Not even sure what the '{}' does in this code. But, I should've mentioned, the index variable 'x' is meant to be an ordering hierarchy on its own. It should always be ascending (i.e. 1,2,3,4, etc). So if the list was 'myList = [0,8,3,5,2,2,4]'. It should still be ascending.

Comment: @Tym, just `sort` the list and you're gonna be alright! About the string formatting syntax (aka `{}`s): check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you are actually comparing an `int` to a `range` object on this line:

```
while x < range(len(myList)):
```

To get the output you desire, it would be much easier to just multiply strings:

```
for i in range(7):
    print(i, i * '@')
```

Adjust the call to `range` if you want to omit the zero row.

Comment: This would only work if the list holds ascending values. Sorry, I should've specified that the list could hold values like: myList = [0,8,3,5,2,2,4]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to do this:

```
>>> myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> for item in myList:
...     if item > 0:
...         print(item, '@' * item)
... 
1 @
2 @@
3 @@@
4 @@@@
5 @@@@@
6 @@@@@@
```

In python you can use the '*' operator to print strings multiple times, like a kind of multiplication.

If you want output a zero but no '@' when the item is zero, remove the `if item > 0:` and dedent the line that follows it.